# Locate files then Grep their contents

Tags: linux, grep, locate

`locate 'filename' | grep 'pattern'` locates files then greps their file names.
I want to grep the contents of the file instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to pass the filenames as arguments to grep:

```
grep 'pattern' $(locate 'filename')
```

(the `$(...)` will evaluate the command and return it's stdoutput)

Comment: @kzarns nobody voted this answer down; if you are wondering why somebody voted your question down, you should consider commenting on the question; the reason why you got downvoted is probably, that it is appreciated if you show what you actually tried to solve your problem (which you didn't)